# Programmatically add column definitions to a DataGrid in Wpf and MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to create a `pivot table` in my user interface.

[image: pivot table in the user interface]

**Note**
Please note that the number of columns are not static.

And this is my `ER diagram`

[image: ER Diagram]

Here is my `Main view model`

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     public ObservableCollection<ColorViewModel> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

`ColorViewModel` class

```cs
public class ColorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public public ObservableCollection<SizeQtyInformationViewModel> SizeQtyInformationList { get; set; }
}
```

`SizeQtyInformationViewModel` class

```cs
public SizeQtyInformationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Size { get; set; }

    public Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

So now, I wanna bind these to the datagrid and get the desired result.

I have an idea but don't know how to implement this.

The Idea is:

If I can define the `column definitions programmatically`, then I will be able to bind columns as well.

Is there any way to implement above idea?
Or is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: I found the answer for this question and I have put the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15780178/873979)