# Edit header in a Dynamic DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a dynamic datagrid as follows

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
```

The `ItemSource` is bound to the following property in the ViewModel

```
private DataTable _myProperty;

public DataTable MyProperty
{
    get {
        return _myProperty;
    }
    set {
        _myProperty= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

Now I wish to make the headers of this DataGrid as editable. How can I do it?

PS: I am populating the datagrid in a similar fashion as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755838/how-to-programmatically-add-columns-to-wpf-datagrid-with-mvvm%22post%22).

Comment: What do you mean by "make the headers editable"?  Are you trying to come up with a UI for editing the headers, or do you simply want to change the header text programmatically?

Comment: change header text programatically